# Loop a selected part of a Powerpoint presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, presentations

I want to create a stream of slide and then loop some of them in order to have a dynamic background when there are some breaks during the presentation.

Any idea how can I do that?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making it all one big show, put the loop slides into another presentation, then add a link to it from the main presentation.  It needn't be visible ... a 99% transparent rectangle with an action setting would do the job, you just need to know where to click something you can't see in order to launch the loop.

When you're done watching the loop, press ESC to close it and you'll be back in the main presentation.